# having trouble with field accessibility

Tags: field-level-security

I have multiple profile and 5 Record type.

I am trying to give one record type "Bill to " from Profile " Technical Support User" but when i click on editable and uncheck visible option in PageLayout it diable for all profile.

any one assist me on this?

Answer (score 2):

You edited the page layout, so all profiles using that record type with that page layout were affected. Instead, consider modifying the field's "Field Level Security" (found on the field's definition page), or assign different profiles different layouts (you can clone the existing one to get started).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure from where you are trying to assign a RecordType to a Profile.

Instead try Open "Technical Support User" Profile -> Search for Record Type Settings on that Page(dont edit Profile in view screen), where all object will be displayed & where you can select which recordtype should be given permission to

[image]